# Postfix configuration : postmap: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: setgid_group =

Tags: postfix

When configuring postfix, Got the following error on `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

```
postmap: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: setgid_group =
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just comment out in `main.cf` the `setgid_group =` line

```
#setgid_group =
```

and rerun

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix
```

Comment: That didn't work here, I had to put in a group name, fortunately postdrop was configured in /etc/group so `setgid_group = postdrop` worked after a postmap