# Postfix is running but it is not listening in any port

Tags: networking, postfix, smtp

this is the postfix status:

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-12-15 19:37:25 -03; 16min ago
    Process: 1099 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1099 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

This is the current configuration:

```
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory =
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path =
manpage_directory =
mydestination = $myhostname, zeus.example.com, localhost.example.com, , localhost
myorigin = /etc/mailname
newaliases_path =
readme_directory =
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sample_directory =
sendmail_path =
setgid_group =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

If I telnet to port 25 (in the same server), this is the result:

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

The same happens with the other ports, such as 587

Finally, this is the output of  `netstat -tuplen`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          23964      861/cpdavd - accept
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      975        18192      1151/node_exporter
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9229          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        24844      1210/gitlab-workhor
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18484      626/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25720      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18500      626/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          7215       1/init
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        24544      1149/puma 6.4.0 (un
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        18239      1141/ruby
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        18238      1141/ruby
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2096            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25721      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          21871      722/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        18254      1354/sidekiq_export
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9236          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        22047      1230/gitaly
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988        16524      648/pdns_server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8150          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        16666      1206/gitlab-kas
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          21744      683/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8151          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        18217      1206/gitlab-kas
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8153          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        16664      1206/gitlab-kas
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988        16533      648/pdns_server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8154          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        22032      1206/gitlab-kas
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5050            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24802      1170/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8155          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        22030      1206/gitlab-kas
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24801      1170/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      979        25528      1352/sidekiq 6.5.12
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24803      1170/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2077            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          23962      861/cpdavd - accept
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2078            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          23963      861/cpdavd - accept
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9121          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978        16643      1157/redis_exporter
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18502      626/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      975        16673      1208/prometheus
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25712      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      977        18167      1152/postgres_expor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:579           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          24650      863/cPhulkd - proce
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25714      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18486      626/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2086            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25713      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25715      620/cpsrvd (SSL) -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      976        18209      1144/registry
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      114        22846      807/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18485      626/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18501      626/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          7219       1/init
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9168                :::*                    LISTEN      979        18237      1141/ruby
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          21872      722/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      988        16525      648/pdns_server
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          21755      683/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18503      626/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18487      626/dovecot
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           988        16520      648/pdns_server
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          7216       1/init
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                988        16521      648/pdns_server
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          7222       1/init
```

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

```
> Ubuntu version: 20.04
> Codename: focal
> Architecture: x86_64
```

EDIT2:

This are other results. It seems this shows the error, but I am not sure about the solution:

```
root@zeus:~# systemctl status postfix
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-12-15 19:37:25 -03; 1h 44min ago
    Process: 1099 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1099 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
root@zeus:~# systemctl status postfix@-.service
● postfix@-.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-12-15 19:37:25 -03; 1h 44min ago
       Docs: man:postfix(1)
    Process: 649 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh - (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 890 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postmulti -i - -p start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 15 19:37:24 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Dec 15 19:37:24 zeus.example.com postmulti[890]: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: setgid_group =
Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: postfix@-.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 19:37:25 zeus.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -).
```

Comment: What OS & release (inc. *architecture*) are you using?  Your paths seem invalid for a Ubuntu install.

Comment: Ubuntu version: 20.04, Codename: focal, Architecture: x86_64

Comment: It looks like you just ran `systemctl status postfix` - you may get some more useful information with `sudo postfix status` and/or `systemctl status postfix@-.service`

Comment: @steeldriver You gave me a clue. The result of `systemctl status postfix@-.service` shows a different output. An error at this time.. Please see my question edit.

Comment: ... so it looks like the same issue as here [Postfix configuration : postmap: fatal: bad string length 0 < 1: setgid_group =](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910701/postfix-configuration-postmap-fatal-bad-string-length-0-1-setgid-group)

Comment: It turned out that there was several configurations I had to comment out. Now, the port 25 is active, but,. I still cannot send e-mails by using RoundCube. I thought it was problem with the SMTP port only :-(